# как попасть с UIAlertControlelr на другой ViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple

[image: Alert]

Имеется у нас 2 ViewController, в первом Вью всплывает AlertController, с кнопки AlertController нужен переход на ViewController2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться segue.

Создаете segue в сториборде:
[image: создание segue]

Присваиваете имя для segue:

[image: ввод имени]

После чего в action вашего алерта выполняете этот segue

Пример кода:

```
 let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Go To", style: .default) { (action) in

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueName", sender: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Да прибудет с вами сила!